# addView does not work (RelativeLayout)

Tags: android

This is my MainActivity XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/testingView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".TestingActivity" >
```

This is the .java file:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testing_activity);

        RelativeLayout viewOne = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.testingView);
        RelativeLayout viewTwo = new RelativeLayout(this);

        viewTwo.setId(5233);
        viewTwo.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000);
```

Then, I tried to add this code (and a lot of other and the same, in differents ways, with differents and fixed sizes, but none of them worked):

```
        viewTwo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

At the end:

```
        viewOne.addView(viewTwo);
```

Tried to add this too, but didn't work:

```
        viewTwo.bringToFront();
```

I just see the white background with the *Hello World!* text.
Any solution?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.testing_activity); change the setcontentview to R.layout.mainactivity

Comment: u sure, you are setting the params for viewTwo right ? i think they should be Relative Layout params. between viewTwo has no content in it. your layout params are wrap_content. it wont show any thing. try changing it to fill_parent just to confirm.

Comment: @AshwinSAshok, my activity is called testing_activity. I don't have an activity with this name: mainactivity.

Comment: @sayed.jalil tried with fill_parent, didn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
viewTwo.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Try this. Since the viewTwo don't have any child you won't see any thing. Try setting a different `backgroundColor` for viewTwo.

```
viewTwo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: I already tried this. It was the first one I tried, but did not work too. I don't know what more I can do.

Comment: Tried with red and black, and this code too: viewTwo.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

RelativeView is container to hold view inside it, of course it is also View, and you can add nested views as well.

How ever when you right some thing like this:

```
viewTwo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You are telling your view to be with the width of it's children. Since you did not added any child to that view the with will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout

```
viewTwo.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

`viewTwo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(Color.RED));`

Updated-

Create a template for your dynamica view like relative layout-

createa xml in your res/layout folder- relative_view_template.xml and copy below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000"
     />
```

and in your class use this code -

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.relative_view_template, null);
```

this is working for me,please try this.

Comment: When I try this, the application crashes. But, I don't think it's something about the background color, as I tried to add an image too.

Comment: You can also add image using same getResources().getDrawable().imagename